# CKAN - Extra fields not displayed in additonal info after typing in values and updating dataset form

Tags: field, ckan

I followed these steps (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html) in the documentation to add extra fields in the Dataset From.

I was able to get the extra fields displayed in "manage" page of dataset form. However, after I type in the value for the extra field and update the dataset form, the extra field is not displayed in the summary page...

Anybody knows how to solve this? Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the CKAN template, [follow the instructions](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#updating-templates) of the tutorial you mentioned.

E.g. in `package/snippets/additional_info.html` add:

```
{% ckan_extends %}

{% block extras %}
  {% if pkg_dict.custom_text %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="dataset-label">{{ _("Custom Text") }}</th>
      <td class="dataset-details">{{ pkg_dict.custom_text }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```